# Is there any way to call dimension of datagridview with listview index

Tags: vb.net, listview

i know that my question is complicated, i dont know how to explain.

i have:

1. datagridview with 2 columns A1 and A2 and A3 ...A200.
2. there is 3 listbox :
   listbox 1 contain the name of datagridview columns header A1 to A200 from this liste i fill listview 2 and 3.
3. for exemple listbox 2 = A1 / listbox 3 = A3

my code:

```
Dim iA1 = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Where ...etc)).ToArray
Dim iA2 = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Where ...etc)).ToArray
Dim iA3 = (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows Where ...etc)).ToArray
Dim iA4 ... iA200

Dim Pearson As Double = Correlation.Pearson(ListBox2, ListBox3).ToString("0.00000")
```

i want to know if it is possible that listbox 1 and 2 can refer to dim A1 and Dim A3

[image]

Comment: you question isn't clear ,do you want to select a vertical values from dgv or what !!

Comment: Im sorry for that explanation, I have declare my columns like in the code dim A1 = ..., to use Pearson i want to select the columns that I want from listview, in that case listeview2 = X = column that I select fro 200 columns in datagridview & listview3 = Y = the same as X, the idea is to do it like SPSS statistics software

Answer (score 0):

This what I understand from your post

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With DataGridView1
            For i As Integer = 0 To 5
                .Columns.Add("ColA" & (i + 1).ToString, "A" & (i + 1).ToString)
                .Columns(i).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To 3
                .Rows.Add()
                For c As Integer = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
                    Randomize()
                    'put some values
                    .Item(c, i).Value = CInt(Rnd() * 30.7)
                Next
            Next

            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .Dock = DockStyle.Top
        End With

    End Sub


    Function ColumnValues(Column As String) As Double()
        Dim col As DataGridViewColumn() = (From cx As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns _
                                           Where UCase(cx.HeaderText) = UCase(Column) _
                                           ).ToArray

        Dim c As Integer = col.Count
        If c <> 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Error :Column [ " & Column & " ] Not found")
            'Or
            'Return Nothing
        End If

        c = col(0).Index


        Return (From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
                Where row.Cells(c).Value IsNot Nothing _
                Select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells(c).FormattedValue) _
                ).ToArray

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim d1 As Double() = ColumnValues("A1")
        Dim d2 As Double() = ColumnValues("a5")

        Dim s As String = "1st Column values " & vbCrLf
        For Each a In d1
            s &= a.ToString & " "
        Next

        s &= vbCrLf & "2nd column values" & vbCrLf
        For Each a In d2
            s &= a.ToString & " "
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(s)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now `d1 and d2` holds the values from `A1 and A5`and no need to declare too many variables which affects on app performance